# MongoDB current date in save method

Tags: javascript, mongodb, date

How to make MongoDB fill a field with current UTC DateTime on save method?
I know there is $currentDate operator, but it's only available in update method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to get access to the time on the mongo server for the insert, right? Mongo _ids encode the timestamp of their creation -- would that work for your needs? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/

Otherwise, I think you might need to provide a date from your application code.